# WebBrowser control inside android layout

Tags: android, browser

I am writting an android application and i want to display a webpage inside my application.

How can i acheive this functionality?

Comment: [Webview](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) would be something that you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take **[WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)** and create a **WebViewClient** instance to display URL inside that WebView.

**Note** that, in order for your Activity to access the Internet and load web pages in a WebView, you must add the INTERNET permissions to your Android Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine the QR code reader functionality and put the read code into the page being loaded with WebView?